# systemd service not working with non-root users

Tags: centos, systemd, glassfish

Im using Glassfish6 on CentOs8. I've made a systemd service for glassfish. but problem is it fails at start up. 
when I start it manually in **/home/gfuser/glassfish6/glassfish/bin/** path, it works but only under sudo privileged: 
 this fails:  `asadmin start-domain` 
 this works:  `sudo asadmin start-domain` 

**glassfish.service** file:    [image: glassfish.service file]

 
when I set `User=root` , it works perfectly , but when I set it to `User=gfuser` , it fails. how can I solve this problem? any idea?

Comment: It fails how? Any error messages or exit code?

Comment: @gronostaj only this: glassfish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Command start-domain failed. 
Im pretty sure problem is about permission or sudo . as I mentioned it works perfectly when I run it  with User=root

Comment: Systemd is a red herring. Once you get the program to work in shell, it will work in systemd too. By the way, please don't post text as images. It's not searchable, not accessible to visually impaired and is barely readable in site's default layout.